# pulseaudio: very sensitive volume (no sound when volume is less than 97%) for USB speaker

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, volume

When using a USB speaker ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y35B44C)) in Ubuntu 20.04, I'm observing something weird: when volume is at 100%, sound is audible (and reasonably loud). However when I gradually decrease the volume (via `pactl set-sink-volume`) by 1%, once I get to 96% there is no longer any audible sound coming out. This is only observed with this particular device (when using HDMI audio output to monitor's speaker or headphones, volume is not that sensitive).

So the question is - what could be causing this level of sensitivity in the volume? Is there any other setting that affects it?

Here's what `pactl` shows for this device:

```
Sink #3
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0-00.analog-stereo
    Description: USB2.0 Device Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 25
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 62909 /  96% / -1.07 dB,   front-right: 62909 /  96% / -1.07 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 8573272 / 13082% / 127.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0-00.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 32357 usec, configured 26000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "USB2.0 Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB2.0 Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-13, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:13:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13:1.0/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1908"
        device.vendor.name = "GEMBIRD"
        device.product.id = "2070"
        device.product.name = "USB2.0 Device"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB2.0_Device_20130100ph0"
        device.string = "front:3"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "384000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "192000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "USB2.0 Device Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900)
    Active Port: analog-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a logidock on Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTA and had this issue. I fixed this via Preferences > Sound > Output > Output Device > Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Logi Dock. It was set to analog when I got there.

Answer (score 0):

The Pulseaudio volumes for input and output devices are translated into ALSA volumes (while the Pulseaudio volumes for applications are applied through calculations).

So if the ALSA "volume" for your USB device only has two values (on/off), that would explain your observation.

You can check with `alsamixer` (make sure to select the USB "soundcard" with <kbd>F6</kbd>).

In general, you should set volumes for input and output devices to one particular level (for me, it's always 100%), and then control the volume per application.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think this is what I observe and what I see confuses me a lot... 

1. `alsamixer` does allow me to set the volume from 0 to 100% and it seems to smoothly raise or lower volume.

2. `pactl set-sink-volume -1%` changes the volume reported by `alsamixer` by 26% (which means using the above command to lower by 4% makes alsamixer report 0% volume and emit no sound).

3. `pavucontrol` is completely unaffected by the above and only affects the app volume.

4. On top of all those things the sound quality from the speaker is somewhat distorted with lot of noise artifacts...

Comment: (4) "Sound quality distorted with clipping artifacts" means some internal mixer settings are too high, so clipping occurs. Use right arrow in `alsamixer` to see if there are more mixers. (2) Pulseaudio changing mixer by 26% when it has 1% resolution is either a Pulseaudio bug, or Pulseaudio is **also** changing some other internal mixer, so potentially the algorithm Pulseaudio applies to map into ALSA mixer settings fails for your card. Either way, that's something that should reported to the Pulseaudio bug tracker.

Comment: Hi. Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but has this been reported anywhere? I have the exact same observations on my own devices and I wish to see that get fixed. I can report it myself if necessary.